# Import failure using the Vendor invoice V2 composite data entity (VendInvoiceV2Entity) in Dynamics 365 (D365) for Finance & Operations

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations, data-entities

I am trying to import vendor invoice using the composite data entity "**Vendor invoice V2**" data entity **(VendInvoiceV2Entity)**, but I am getting the following error:

> Package execution failed please check event log in DMF service box
> '0' 'Vendor invoice V2' record(s) inserted in staging

[image: DMF Execution Log]

I am using the following file for import:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <VENDORINVOICEHEADERENTITY>
    <HEADERREFERENCE>VT01-002123</HEADERREFERENCE>
    <APPROVEPOSTINGWITHMATCHINGDISCREPANCIES>0</APPROVEPOSTINGWITHMATCHINGDISCREPANCIES>
    <APPROVERPERSONNELNUMBER>000001</APPROVERPERSONNELNUMBER>
    <BANKACCOUNT />
    <BUSINESSDOCUMENTSUBMISSIONID_W>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</BUSINESSDOCUMENTSUBMISSIONID_W>
    <CASHDISCOUNT>0.000000</CASHDISCOUNT>
    <CASHDISCOUNTCODE />
    <CASHDISCOUNTDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</CASHDISCOUNTDATE>
    <CHARGESGROUP />
    <COMMENT_ />
    <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
    <DATE>2022-06-02T00:00:00+00:00</DATE>
    <DELIVERYNAME>New address created from PO</DELIVERYNAME>
    <DIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE />
    <DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>0.000000</DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>
    <DOCUMENTNUMBER />
    <DUEDATE>2022-07-02T00:00:00+00:00</DUEDATE>
    <ENDDATETIME>1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</ENDDATETIME>
    <EXCHANGERATE>100.0000000000000000</EXCHANGERATE>
    <FIXEDRATE>0</FIXEDRATE>
    <HEADERONLYIMPORT>0</HEADERONLYIMPORT>
    <IGNORECALCULATEDSALESTAX>0</IGNORECALCULATEDSALESTAX>
    <IMPORTEDAMOUNT>0.000000</IMPORTEDAMOUNT>
    <IMPORTEDSALESTAX>0.000000</IMPORTEDSALESTAX>
    <INVOICEACCOUNT>000509</INVOICEACCOUNT>
    <INVOICEDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</INVOICEDATE>
    <INVOICEDESCRIPTION />
    <INVOICEGROUP />
    <INVOICENUMBER />
    <INVOICEPAYMENTRELEASEDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</INVOICEPAYMENTRELEASEDATE>
    <INVOICERECEIVEDDATE>2022-06-02T00:00:00+00:00</INVOICERECEIVEDDATE>
    <INVOICEROUNDOFF>0.000000</INVOICEROUNDOFF>
    <ISAPPROVED>1</ISAPPROVED>
    <ISBATCH>1</ISBATCH>
    <ISONHOLD>0</ISONHOLD>
    <ISPRICESINCLUDESALESTAX>0</ISPRICESINCLUDESALESTAX>
    <LOG />
    <METHODOFPAYMENT />
    <NUMBERSEQUENCEGROUP />
    <OVERRIDESALESTAX>0</OVERRIDESALESTAX>
    <PACKINGSLIPRANGE />
    <PAYMENTGROUPCODE />
    <PAYMENTID />
    <PAYMENTSCHEDULE />
    <PAYMENTSPECIFICATION />
    <PORT />
    <POSTINGPROFILE />
    <PSNBANKACCOUNTID />
    <PSNCARDHOLDERNAME />
    <PSNCARDNUMBERDIGITS />
    <PSNPOSTINGDEFINITIONCODE />
    <PSNPURCHASINGCARDTRANSACTIONTYPE>0</PSNPURCHASINGCARDTRANSACTIONTYPE>
    <PSNREFERENCEINVOICENUMBER />
    <PSNVENDORACCOUNTFORBALANCEPAYOFF />
    <PURCHIDRANGE />
    <RECALCULATION>1</RECALCULATION>
    <RELEASEDATECOMMENT />
    <REPORTINGCURRENCYEXCHANGERATE>100.0000000000000000</REPORTINGCURRENCYEXCHANGERATE>
    <SALESTAXGROUP />
    <SALESTAXROUNDING>0.000000</SALESTAXROUNDING>
    <SECONDARYEXCHANGERATE>0.0000000000000000</SECONDARYEXCHANGERATE>
    <SETTLEVOUCHER>0</SETTLEVOUCHER>
    <SITE />
    <STARTDATETIME>1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</STARTDATETIME>
    <STATISTICSPROCEDURE />
    <TAXEXEMPTNUMBER />
    <TERMSOFPAYMENT />
    <TOTALDISCOUNT>0.000000</TOTALDISCOUNT>
    <TRANSACTIONCODE />
    <TRANSPORT />
    <TRIANGULATION>0</TRIANGULATION>
    <VARIANCEAPPROVEDDATETIME>1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</VARIANCEAPPROVEDDATETIME>
    <VARIANCEPERSONNELNUMBER>000001</VARIANCEPERSONNELNUMBER>
    <VENDORACCOUNT>000509</VENDORACCOUNT>
    <VENDORINVOICEREVIEWSTATUS>0</VENDORINVOICEREVIEWSTATUS>
    <VENDORINVOICETYPE>0</VENDORINVOICETYPE>
    <VENDORNAME>MY XYZ VENDOR</VENDORNAME>
    <VENDORREQUESTEDWORKEREMAIL>shakir.shabbir52@gmail.com</VENDORREQUESTEDWORKEREMAIL>
    <WAREHOUSE />
    <VENDORINVOICELINEENTITY>
      <HEADERREFERENCE>VT01-002123</HEADERREFERENCE>
      <INVOICELINENUMBER>1.0000000000000000</INVOICELINENUMBER>
      <ACCOUNTINGDISTRIBUTIONTEMPLATEID />
      <AMOUNT>0.000000</AMOUNT>
      <BUDGETRESERVATIONDOCUMENTNUMBER />
      <BUDGETRESERVATIONLINENUMBER>0</BUDGETRESERVATIONLINENUMBER>
      <CHANGEQUANTITYMANUALLY>0</CHANGEQUANTITYMANUALLY>
      <CHARGESONPURCHASES>0.000000</CHARGESONPURCHASES>
      <CLOSEFORRECEIPT>0</CLOSEFORRECEIPT>
      <COMMODITY />
      <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
      <CWDELIVERYREMAINDER>0.000000</CWDELIVERYREMAINDER>
      <CWREMAININGQUANTITY>0.000000</CWREMAININGQUANTITY>
      <CWUPDATE>0.000000</CWUPDATE>
      <DATAAREACOMPANY />
      <DELIVERYNAME>New address created from PO</DELIVERYNAME>
      <DELIVERYSTATE />
      <DIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE />
      <DIMENSIONNUMBER>#00000001500031DB</DIMENSIONNUMBER>
      <DISCOUNT>0.000000</DISCOUNT>
      <DISCOUNTPERCENT>0.000000</DISCOUNTPERCENT>
      <INVENTNOW>3000.000000</INVENTNOW>
      <INVENTORYSITEID>1001</INVENTORYSITEID>
      <INVENTORYWAREHOUSEID>1001.255</INVENTORYWAREHOUSEID>
      <INVOICEACCOUNT>000509</INVOICEACCOUNT>
      <ISTAX1099GTRADEORBUSINESSINCOME>0</ISTAX1099GTRADEORBUSINESSINCOME>
      <ISTAX1099SPROPERTYORSERVICES>0</ISTAX1099SPROPERTYORSERVICES>
      <ITEMBATCHNUMBER />
      <ITEMNAME>My Item name</ITEMNAME>
      <ITEMNUMBER>100018</ITEMNUMBER>
      <ITEMSALESTAX />
      <LINEDESCRIPTION />
      <LINENUMBER>1.0000000000000000</LINENUMBER>
      <LINETYPE>0</LINETYPE>
      <MAINACCOUNTDISPLAYVALUE />
      <MULTILINEDISCOUNT>0.000000</MULTILINEDISCOUNT>
      <MULTILINEDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>0.000000</MULTILINEDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>
      <NETAMOUNT>65.610000</NETAMOUNT>
      <ORDEREDINVENTORYSTATUSID />
      <ORIGCOUNTRYREGIONID />
      <ORIGINALDELIVERREMAINDER>3000.000000</ORIGINALDELIVERREMAINDER>
      <OVERRIDESALESTAX>0</OVERRIDESALESTAX>
      <PARTYID />
      <PERCENTAGE>0.000000</PERCENTAGE>
      <PORT />
      <PRICEUNIT>1.000000000000</PRICEUNIT>
      <PROCUREMENTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME>Main</PROCUREMENTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME>
      <PROCUREMENTCATEGORYNAME>Lab Supplies</PROCUREMENTCATEGORYNAME>
      <PRODUCTCOLORID />
      <PRODUCTCONFIGURATIONID />
      <PRODUCTSIZEID />
      <PRODUCTSTYLEID />
      <PURCHASEORDER>VT01-000741</PURCHASEORDER>
      <PURCHLINENUMBER>1</PURCHLINENUMBER>
      <RECEIVENOW>3.000000</RECEIVENOW>
      <RELEASEALLRETAINEDAMOUNT>0</RELEASEALLRETAINEDAMOUNT>
      <REMAINAFTER>0.000000</REMAINAFTER>
      <REMAINAFTERINVENT>0.000000</REMAINAFTERINVENT>
      <REMAINBEFOREINVENT>3000.000000</REMAINBEFOREINVENT>
      <RETAINAGEAMOUNT>0.000000</RETAINAGEAMOUNT>
      <RETAINPERCENTAGE>0.000000</RETAINPERCENTAGE>
      <SALESTAXGROUP />
      <STATEOFORIGIN />
      <STATISTICSPROCEDURE />
      <TAX1099AMOUNT>0.000000</TAX1099AMOUNT>
      <TAX1099BOX />
      <TAX1099GSTATETAXWITHHELDAMOUNT>0.000000</TAX1099GSTATETAXWITHHELDAMOUNT>
      <TAX1099GTAXYEAR>0</TAX1099GTAXYEAR>
      <TAX1099GVENDORSTATEID />
      <TAX1099GVENDORSTATETAXID />
      <TAX1099SADDRESSORLEGALDESCRIPTION />
      <TAX1099SBUYERPARTOFREALESTATETAXAMOUNT>0.000000</TAX1099SBUYERPARTOFREALESTATETAXAMOUNT>
      <TAX1099STATEAMOUNT>0.000000</TAX1099STATEAMOUNT>
      <TAX1099TYPE>0</TAX1099TYPE>
      <TAXWITHHOLDGROUP />
      <TAXWITHHOLDITEMGROUPNAME />
      <TRANSACTIONCODE />
      <TRANSPORT />
      <UNIT />
      <UNITPRICE>21.870000</UNITPRICE>
      <VENDORACCOUNT>000509</VENDORACCOUNT>
      <VENDORINVOICELINEREVIEWSTATUS>0</VENDORINVOICELINEREVIEWSTATUS>
      <WITHHOLDINGTAXGROUP />
    </VENDORINVOICELINEENTITY>
  </VENDORINVOICEHEADERENTITY>
</Document>
```

I checked the "**Event log**" as well, but did not get any useful information

[image: Event Log]

Comment: Just curious - have you search on google or in the Microsoft Dynamics AX Forum about this issue? - this [entry](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/190189/error-dixf-0-vendor-records-inserted-in-staging?pifragment-109373=2#responses) might help

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Yes, I have researched it before - Also, investigated this as much as I could have done. I am working this morning as well to further drill this down and if I have a solution, I will post the solution.

Answer (score 2):

## TLDR;

The issue of the question is probably caused by a data issue and not by a bug in the import/export framework logic. Without having access to an environment with that data, there is probably little that can be provided in terms of an answer to the specific issue of the question. But here are some general pointers on how to further analyze the issue.

## Creating a working baseline

In general, when setting up an import for a complex entity like Vendor Invoice V2, I recommend the following process:

1. First, manually create a few data samples in the system (in this case, a pending vendor invoice). The samples should be entered with the same data that you expect from the import.
2. Second, create an export project and export the data samples. This will give you a template file that you can use for the import.
3. Third, create the import project with the template file.
4. Check that the import works with the template file. You should delete the sample data first to make sure the import creates new records instead of updating them.
5. Modify a copy of the template file to include additional import data. Import that modified copy.

Steps 1-4 are important to establish a working base line. The bulk of the work will probably be step 5. Usually, at this step, numerous issues with the import data are uncovered.

## Working Contoso sample and additional ideas

Following this process, I was able to set up a working import on a 10.0.28 environment with Contoso demo data in the USMF legal entity. See below for the xml data that I used.

While testing this and when comparing my xml data with the one from the question, I noticed the following issues that may be worth investigating:

- During setup of the import project, the mapping was first shown with a red x symbol. This was due to the unmapped field `COMMENT_`, which only seems to be supported for export, but not import. I removed it from the mapping and the red x was gone.
- The xml data in the question has a field `PURCHASEORDER` in the line data, but the field is missing in the header data.
- A couple of fields in my xml data have values, while the xml data of the question does not, and vice versa. Nothing obvious was jumping out at me for causing issues. But I recommend reviewing the import data carefully for any issues.

Working sample data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <VENDORINVOICEHEADERENTITY>
        <HEADERREFERENCE>012222</HEADERREFERENCE>
        <APPROVEPOSTINGWITHMATCHINGDISCREPANCIES>0</APPROVEPOSTINGWITHMATCHINGDISCREPANCIES>
        <APPROVERPERSONNELNUMBER>000020</APPROVERPERSONNELNUMBER>
        <BANKACCOUNT />
        <BUSINESSDOCUMENTSUBMISSIONID_W>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</BUSINESSDOCUMENTSUBMISSIONID_W>
        <CASHDISCOUNT>0.000000</CASHDISCOUNT>
        <CASHDISCOUNTCODE>0.5%D10</CASHDISCOUNTCODE>
        <CASHDISCOUNTDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</CASHDISCOUNTDATE>
        <CHARGESGROUP />
        <COMMENT_ />
        <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
        <DATE>2022-06-15T00:00:00+02:00</DATE>
        <DELIVERYNAME>Contoso Entertainment System USA</DELIVERYNAME>
        <DIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE>001--</DIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE>
        <DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>0.500000</DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>
        <DOCUMENTNUMBER />
        <DUEDATE>2022-07-15T00:00:00+02:00</DUEDATE>
        <ENDDATETIME>1900-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</ENDDATETIME>
        <EXCHANGERATE>100.0000000000000000</EXCHANGERATE>
        <FIXEDRATE>0</FIXEDRATE>
        <HEADERONLYIMPORT>0</HEADERONLYIMPORT>
        <IGNORECALCULATEDSALESTAX>0</IGNORECALCULATEDSALESTAX>
        <IMPORTEDAMOUNT>0.000000</IMPORTEDAMOUNT>
        <IMPORTEDSALESTAX>0.000000</IMPORTEDSALESTAX>
        <INVOICEACCOUNT>1001</INVOICEACCOUNT>
        <INVOICEDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</INVOICEDATE>
        <INVOICEDESCRIPTION />
        <INVOICEGROUP />
        <INVOICENUMBER>4711</INVOICENUMBER>
        <INVOICEPAYMENTRELEASEDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</INVOICEPAYMENTRELEASEDATE>
        <INVOICERECEIVEDDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</INVOICERECEIVEDDATE>
        <INVOICEROUNDOFF>0.000000</INVOICEROUNDOFF>
        <ISAPPROVED>1</ISAPPROVED>
        <ISBATCH>0</ISBATCH>
        <ISONHOLD>0</ISONHOLD>
        <ISPRICESINCLUDESALESTAX>0</ISPRICESINCLUDESALESTAX>
        <LOG />
        <METHODOFPAYMENT>CHECK</METHODOFPAYMENT>
        <NUMBERSEQUENCEGROUP />
        <OVERRIDESALESTAX>0</OVERRIDESALESTAX>
        <PACKINGSLIPRANGE />
        <PAYMENTGROUPCODE />
        <PAYMENTID />
        <PAYMENTSCHEDULE />
        <PAYMENTSPECIFICATION />
        <PORT />
        <POSTINGPROFILE>GEN</POSTINGPROFILE>
        <PSNBANKACCOUNTID />
        <PSNCARDHOLDERNAME />
        <PSNCARDNUMBERDIGITS />
        <PSNPOSTINGDEFINITIONCODE />
        <PSNPURCHASINGCARDTRANSACTIONTYPE>0</PSNPURCHASINGCARDTRANSACTIONTYPE>
        <PSNREFERENCEINVOICENUMBER />
        <PSNVENDORACCOUNTFORBALANCEPAYOFF />
        <PURCHASEORDERNUMBER />
        <PURCHIDRANGE />
        <RECALCULATION>1</RECALCULATION>
        <RELEASEDATECOMMENT />
        <REPORTINGCURRENCYEXCHANGERATE>100.0000000000000000</REPORTINGCURRENCYEXCHANGERATE>
        <SALESTAXGROUP />
        <SALESTAXROUNDING>0.000000</SALESTAXROUNDING>
        <SECONDARYEXCHANGERATE>0.0000000000000000</SECONDARYEXCHANGERATE>
        <SETTLEVOUCHER>0</SETTLEVOUCHER>
        <SITE />
        <STARTDATETIME>1900-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</STARTDATETIME>
        <STATISTICSPROCEDURE />
        <TAXEXEMPTNUMBER />
        <TERMSOFPAYMENT>Net30</TERMSOFPAYMENT>
        <TOTALDISCOUNT>0.000000</TOTALDISCOUNT>
        <TRANSACTIONCODE />
        <TRANSPORT />
        <TRIANGULATION>0</TRIANGULATION>
        <VARIANCEAPPROVEDDATETIME>1900-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</VARIANCEAPPROVEDDATETIME>
        <VARIANCEPERSONNELNUMBER>000020</VARIANCEPERSONNELNUMBER>
        <VENDORACCOUNT>1001</VENDORACCOUNT>
        <VENDORINVOICEREVIEWSTATUS>0</VENDORINVOICEREVIEWSTATUS>
        <VENDORINVOICETYPE>0</VENDORINVOICETYPE>
        <VENDORNAME>Acme Office Supplies</VENDORNAME>
        <VENDORREQUESTEDWORKEREMAIL>julia@contoso.com</VENDORREQUESTEDWORKEREMAIL>
        <WAREHOUSE />
        <VENDORINVOICELINEENTITY>
            <HEADERREFERENCE>012222</HEADERREFERENCE>
            <INVOICELINENUMBER>1.0000000000000000</INVOICELINENUMBER>
            <ACCOUNTINGDISTRIBUTIONTEMPLATEID />
            <ADJUSTEDUNITPRICE>0.000000</ADJUSTEDUNITPRICE>
            <AMOUNT>0.000000</AMOUNT>
            <BUDGETRESERVATIONDOCUMENTNUMBER />
            <BUDGETRESERVATIONLINENUMBER>0</BUDGETRESERVATIONLINENUMBER>
            <CHANGEQUANTITYMANUALLY>0</CHANGEQUANTITYMANUALLY>
            <CHARGESONPURCHASES>0.000000</CHARGESONPURCHASES>
            <CLOSEFORRECEIPT>0</CLOSEFORRECEIPT>
            <COMMODITY />
            <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
            <CWDELIVERYREMAINDER>0.000000</CWDELIVERYREMAINDER>
            <CWREMAININGQUANTITY>0.000000</CWREMAININGQUANTITY>
            <CWUPDATE>0.000000</CWUPDATE>
            <DATAAREACOMPANY />
            <DELIVERYNAME>Site 1</DELIVERYNAME>
            <DELIVERYSTATE />
            <DIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE>001--</DIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE>
            <DIMENSIONNUMBER>000252</DIMENSIONNUMBER>
            <DISCOUNT>0.000000</DISCOUNT>
            <DISCOUNTPERCENT>0.000000</DISCOUNTPERCENT>
            <INVENTNOW>0.000000</INVENTNOW>
            <INVENTORYSITEID>1</INVENTORYSITEID>
            <INVENTORYWAREHOUSEID>13</INVENTORYWAREHOUSEID>
            <INVOICEACCOUNT>1001</INVOICEACCOUNT>
            <ISTAX1099GTRADEORBUSINESSINCOME>0</ISTAX1099GTRADEORBUSINESSINCOME>
            <ISTAX1099SPROPERTYORSERVICES>0</ISTAX1099SPROPERTYORSERVICES>
            <ITEMBATCHNUMBER />
            <ITEMNAME>Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite / Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite</ITEMNAME>
            <ITEMNUMBER>C0001</ITEMNUMBER>
            <ITEMSALESTAX>ALL</ITEMSALESTAX>
            <LINEDESCRIPTION>Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite</LINEDESCRIPTION>
            <LINENUMBER>0.0000000000000000</LINENUMBER>
            <LINETYPE>0</LINETYPE>
            <MAINACCOUNTDISPLAYVALUE />
            <MULTILINEDISCOUNT>0.000000</MULTILINEDISCOUNT>
            <MULTILINEDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>0.000000</MULTILINEDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>
            <NETAMOUNT>39.950000</NETAMOUNT>
            <ORDEREDINVENTORYSTATUSID />
            <ORIGCOUNTRYREGIONID />
            <ORIGINALDELIVERREMAINDER>0.000000</ORIGINALDELIVERREMAINDER>
            <OVERRIDESALESTAX>0</OVERRIDESALESTAX>
            <PARTYID />
            <PDSCALCULATIONID />
            <PERCENTAGE>0.000000</PERCENTAGE>
            <PORT />
            <PRICEUNIT>1.000000000000</PRICEUNIT>
            <PROCUREMENTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME>Procurement - Office Supplies</PROCUREMENTCATEGORYHIERARCHYNAME>
            <PROCUREMENTCATEGORYNAME>Computers</PROCUREMENTCATEGORYNAME>
            <PRODUCTCOLORID>Black</PRODUCTCOLORID>
            <PRODUCTCONFIGURATIONID />
            <PRODUCTSIZEID />
            <PRODUCTSTYLEID />
            <PURCHASEORDER />
            <PURCHLINENUMBER>0</PURCHLINENUMBER>
            <RECEIVENOW>1.000000</RECEIVENOW>
            <RELEASEALLRETAINEDAMOUNT>0</RELEASEALLRETAINEDAMOUNT>
            <REMAINAFTER>0.000000</REMAINAFTER>
            <REMAINAFTERINVENT>0.000000</REMAINAFTERINVENT>
            <REMAINBEFORE>0.000000</REMAINBEFORE>
            <REMAINBEFOREINVENT>0.000000</REMAINBEFOREINVENT>
            <RETAINAGEAMOUNT>0.000000</RETAINAGEAMOUNT>
            <RETAINPERCENTAGE>0.000000</RETAINPERCENTAGE>
            <SALESTAXGROUP />
            <STATEOFORIGIN />
            <STATISTICSPROCEDURE />
            <TAX1099AMOUNT>0.000000</TAX1099AMOUNT>
            <TAX1099BOX />
            <TAX1099GSTATETAXWITHHELDAMOUNT>0.000000</TAX1099GSTATETAXWITHHELDAMOUNT>
            <TAX1099GTAXYEAR>0</TAX1099GTAXYEAR>
            <TAX1099GVENDORSTATEID />
            <TAX1099GVENDORSTATETAXID />
            <TAX1099SADDRESSORLEGALDESCRIPTION />
            <TAX1099SBUYERPARTOFREALESTATETAXAMOUNT>0.000000</TAX1099SBUYERPARTOFREALESTATETAXAMOUNT>
            <TAX1099STATEAMOUNT>0.000000</TAX1099STATEAMOUNT>
            <TAX1099TYPE>0</TAX1099TYPE>
            <TAXWITHHOLDGROUP />
            <TAXWITHHOLDITEMGROUPNAME />
            <TOTALRETAINEDAMOUNT>0.000000</TOTALRETAINEDAMOUNT>
            <TRANSACTIONCODE />
            <TRANSPORT />
            <UNIT>ea</UNIT>
            <UNITPRICE>39.950000</UNITPRICE>
            <VENDORACCOUNT>1001</VENDORACCOUNT>
            <VENDORINVOICELINEREVIEWSTATUS>0</VENDORINVOICELINEREVIEWSTATUS>
            <WITHHOLDINGTAXGROUP />
        </VENDORINVOICELINEENTITY>
    </VENDORINVOICEHEADERENTITY>
</Document>
```